# Turning on LEDs in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve the following question:

"You have a 16x16 grid populated by LEDs where the columns are represented from 0-15 bits and the rows are only represented by two bytes 0-1. Write a C script to turn on any of the given LEDs. The variable name that represents the array of LEDs is  LEDs[16][2]."

I'm really not sure how to approach this problem as I've never had to deal with bits and bytes in my code. I know that a good way to turn on the LEDs would be to go to the particular array index I want and set its value to, say, "0x01," but I don't know how to actually index this array. I also know that bytes are typically written as "0x00, 0xFF" etc. but how would you represent bits? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry forgot to post code

```
int main() {
    char LEDs[16][2];//Assuming char array since chars are 1 byte
    char col, row;

    printf("Enter col and row: \n");
    scanf("%c %c\n", col, row);

    //Turn on LED
    LEDs[col][row] = 0x01;
    //Turn off LED
    LEDs[col][row] = 0x00;
}
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Bit `i` is `1<<i`, where `i` is a value 0-7.  Use bitwise-OR to turn on, bitwise-XOR to toggle, or bitwise-AND with the inverse mask to turn off.

Comment: Why don't you do a search? Many resources on this site and others that cover bit operations in C.

Comment: I have already done a search. I know how to turn on the LEDs. It's indexing the array I don't understand. According to the question the indexes are done in bits and bytes.

Comment: @Nick But you still haven't really explained the problem properly. You say the columns are represented by 16 bits, but the rows are "only" represented by two bytes. Are you unaware that two bytes also contain 16 bits? Why is the LED array represented as an array of 16x2 bytes? How are these array elements mapped to the LEDs themselves? It seems to me that you're asking us to do your homework for you without even showing us the whole question. Your example code makes no sense. If `row` and `column` can both take values from 0–15, then the statement `LEDs[col][row] = 0x01;` clearly won't work...

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
uint16_t LEDs[16] //Each one is 16 bits
unsigned char row,col;

//Turn on LED
LEDs[row] |= 0x1 << col;
//Turn off LED
LEDs[row] &= ~(0x1 << col);
//Toggle LEDs
LEDs[row] ^= 0x1 << col;
```

You probably want some checks that the numbers are in the right range, too.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps. I'm not sure how this would address a 16x16 array though. Wouldn't this be a (16^2)x1 array?

Comment: It's effectively a 16x16 array, though C doesn't see it like that. You're treating a single 16 bit number as an array of bits. So you have an array of 16 arrays of 16 bits. You can address each single bit with bit shifts.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is row-based.  That is, there are 16 rows each holding two bytes.  Since the column value can be 0-15, you must first figure out which of the two bytes it goes in, and which bit it corresponds to.

Perhaps this makes it clearer:

```
col  | 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 | 8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15
-----+------------------------+-------------------------
byte | 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 | 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
bit  | 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 | 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

This can be achieved as follows:

```
int which_byte = col / 8;
int which_bit = col % 8;
LEDS[row][which_byte] |= (1 << which_bit);
```

You can perform the division and modulo with bitwise operations if you want, but this doesn't make it quite as clear as the above example.

```
int which_byte = col >> 3;
int which_bit = col & 7;
```

Comment: This helps a ton thank you! Sorry for the lack of posted code, this question was more of a thought experiment for me as I prep for an interview.

Comment: No offense, but this is basic stuff.  I assumed it was homework for a course.  Who is hiring C programmers who don't know 2D array indexing and simple math?

Comment: Its for an internship, I'm actually still in school. I've taken a few C classes but I've never dealt with bitwise operations, hence the confusion.

Comment: Well, good luck with the interview, and have fun learning the C language =)